# Coming up with a Research Topic for Undergraduate Paper

Tags: applied-econometrics, research

I am currently a senior in economics, and I have been pondering ideas for doing a research paper. Sometimes I go about thinking theory and trying to find applications I could apply it to empirically, sometimes I will look through datasets and see if anything interesting might come to mind, and sometimes I will just happen to think up something that could possibly be an interesting idea related to economics.

For the most part, I don't think any of the ideas I've come upon have much substance for a paper. I was wondering if anyone would happen to have any suggestions for the creative process of coming up with a topic? Considering it is undergraduate, I realize that it likely won't be anything too substantial or different than what has been studied in the field already, but I would like it to be atleast somewhat unique.

I have taken econometrics I and II, and I am leaning towards some type of research involving panel data as being the main possibility.

Comment: One good strategy for generating questions is to look for two theoretical models that produce different, perhaps even competing, predictions and then do an empirical study to test which (if either) model makes the better prediction.